# How to delete a specific node in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I previously needed help debugging my deleteNode method. It works now (updated version posted below) but I want it to provide for the case when it has to delete the head node. At the moment, it returns a NullPointerException where I've inserted *** in deleteNode. I don't know how any of my variables can be null at that point, seeing as my while loop requires both `position` and `head` to not be null in the first place.

```
public class LinkedList
{
private class Node
{
    int item;
    Node link;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public Node()
    {
        item = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        link = null;
    }
    public Node(int x, Node p)
    {
        item = x;
        link = p;
    }
}

private Node head;

public LinkedList()
{
    head = null;
}

public boolean deleteNode (int target)
{
    Node position = head;
    boolean isGone = false;

    while(position != null && head != null)
    {
        if(position.link == head && position.link.item == target)
        {
            head = head.link;
            isGone = true;
            return isGone;
        }
    *** else if(position.link.item == target && position.link != head)
        {
            position.link = position.link.link;
            isGone = true;
            return isGone;
        }
        position = position.link;
    }
    return isGone;
}

public void printList()
{
    System.out.println("Your list is: ");
    Node position = head;
    while(position != null)
    {
        System.out.println(position.item + " ");
        position = position.link;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and find out what it's not doing correctly

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedList.deleteNode(int)` never modifies any node's `link`, so it doesn't remove any element from the list.

Suppose that `nodeA.link == nodeB`, and `nodeB.item == target`. Then you need to set `nodeA.link = nodeB.link`, so that nothing is pointing to `nodeB` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the problems I see:

1. The enumerator you actually want to use, `position`, is never updated.  The enumerator that is updated, `counter` is not needed.
2. You are never actually removing the node. In order to remove the node, you need to set the previous node's link to the matching node's link, thus removing it out of the chain.
3. You aren't dealing with special cases.  What happens if the list passed is null? What happens if the matching node is the first node? The last node?
4. You should be returning the head of the linked list from the calling function.  This is required for when removing the head node of the linked list.

Since this is a homework question, try to work it out for yourself but hopefully those points will help.

Comment: Thanks for the points, but could you explain the second bit, please? If I understand things correctly, my code `position=position.link` just continues on to the next link, basically traversing the list but not actually doing anything. I guess I'm not sure how to delete the link without using both `position` and `counter`.

Comment: That is correct. If this is a singly-linked list, what you should be doing is actually comparing against current.next, which in this case is `position.link.item`, then if that is the match, remove the links around `position.link`, i.e. `position.link = position.link.link`.  Just make sure you account for the special case where the head node is the node to be deleted before you get to this `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the bug and now the loop works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear.  Make sure you test for the special cases I mentioned in point 3, that will prove whether it really works perfectly or not :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your deleteNode() while loop code.

```
while(position != null && counter != null)
    {
        itemAtPosition = position.item;
        if(itemAtPosition == target)
        {
            position = position.link;
            isGone = true;
        }
        counter = counter.link;
    }
```

you update counter, but never refer to it.  position never changes, so the

```
if(itemAtPosition == target)
```

line never returns true.  I suspect somewhere you need to check on counter.item!

Comment: I agree, position & counter you just need to use one. The idea here is using only a node as current node and keep assigning current_node = current_node.link until target is found.

Answer (score 0):

First, you didn't write code for the case where the target item is located at the beginning, in which the field **head** should be updated accordingly. Second, the compared item is never updated during traversing the list.