# How to delete nodes in linked list?

Tags: java

What would a replace method look like when deleting a node?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305273/how-to-delete-a-specific-node-in-a-linked-list?rq=1.

Answer (score 1):

The following logic should work:

```
if (position.c > 0) {
    position.c--; 
    if (position.c == 0) {
        // delete entire node
        if (previous == null) {
            // delete head node
            head = position.next;
        } else {
            // delete a node with a predecessor
            previous.next = position.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've reversed the `next` assignment from what was in your code. All you did was terminate the list with a circular reference at `position` (since `previous.next == position` at that point).

As an aside, you don't need the `if` statement here:

```
found = true;
if(found==true){
    . . .
}
```

It can just be:

```
found = true;
. . .
```